# Is there raster equivalent to vector Intersect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster

The intersect tool that is used on vector data cannot be used on raster data.

What tool can I use for my two rasters that does the same as the Overlay > Intersect tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell in a raster can only have 1 value so the concept of intersect in vector does not apply to raster data.

You do not describe what your data is or the range of values so assuming your first raster has values 1,2 & 3 then make you second have 10,100 & 1000 then add them together and the combination of values will give you what intersects what.

Answer (score 2):

It is SA-Local-Combine. Make sure your rasters are integers